# How can I stop git difftool?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-diff, meld, git-difftool

I use **Meld** as tool for *difftool* and *mergetool* in Git Bash.
When I run `git difftool` it opens a window of Meld and, every time I close the window with a difference, it opens a new window with the next difference. And so on, they could be hundreds...
Is there a way to stop Meld from the terminal (e.g. I didn't expect all these differences and now I want to make some changes in order to limit the number of them)?
The only way I found is to directly close the terminal, but I'd like a less brutal mode.

Comment: `Ctrl+c` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tried `git config --global --add difftool.prompt false`? Or what @Biffen already commented: `Ctrl+C` in the terminal.

Comment: I'd like to see all the windows as it already happens, but I think that if they are too much I need something to stop it. However using `Ctrl+C` works! The only drawback is that now Meld crashes but never mind, the terminal continues to work.